# Node.js 6 and anonymous objects

Tags: node.js, console

Does anybody know why starting from Node.js 6.0 `console.log` sometimes renders objects with leading `anonymous` word?

```
anonymous {val: 123}
```

What does it mean, and how to counter it?

I am getting it for objects from some libraries that I'm using.

Comment: This is usually caused when directly passing an object into a function.  Like, jimmy({test:'123'}).  You could try setting var obj={test:'123'}; jimmy(obj).  This may solve your problem.

Comment: If I just do it like this, it doesn't reproduce. Must be something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a feature that was first introduced in Node.js 6.0.0, that upon object inspection via `util.inspect` prefixes anonymous objects with string `anonymous`  when such objects are written into the console, which denotes anonymous object instantiation.

It does not affect the functionality, and is perfectly ok to ignore.

Comment: well, for example Seneca sees this as an error: `Error: seneca: Action cmd:get,role:project responded with result that was not an object or array: anonymous {...}`

Comment: @yentsun I'm guessing, it is using `util.inspect` to output a string and then compares the console render. That's not a good practice, as it barely ever represents a valid object state.

Comment: downgrading Node version to 4.x didn't fix the error: `Error: seneca: Action cmd:get,role:project responded with result that was not an object or array: {...}`, so I guess it's Seneca-related error and you were right - `anonymous {}` doesn't affect functionality :)

Comment: is there a way (flag) to turn it off, so node does not print `anonymous`?

Comment: @MuratOzgul No, it is not possible to turn off.