# Cant able to fetch the data from postgres sql anonymous block in Nodejs using pg npm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, pg, pg-promise

I was trying to fetch the data from postgres sql using nodejs.

I have been using npm pg to establish the connection to database. Using select query trying to fetch all the data from postgres but PostgreSQL returns the data in anonymous block.

I was unable to get the data from anonymous block. If try to get the data it returns as undefined.

Can anyone please help me out? [Please see my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcDBG.png)

```
 anonymous {

   Id: 10062,

   Animal: 'horse',

   Breed: 'American Quarter',

   Age: 'Adult',

   Sex: 'male',

   Size: 'Medium',

   Color: 'Green',

   Status: 'Homestay' 
},
```

From this I want to get the Breed alone, but it does not affect my functionality, bu unable to get the individual value from the block
please see my code below:

```
function selectAllRecords{
    /**
    * pool is my connection object,initiall a pool of connection is created
    * This function fetch all the records from the table
    */
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {               
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);               
        }    
        client.query('select * from petpoint', function(err, result) {            
            done(); 
            if(err) {
                return console.error('error running tracking table query', err);}
                console.log(result.rows);               //output will be in postgres anonymous block
                console.log(result.rows.Id)             //undefined
                console.log(result.rows.anonymous.Id)   //undefined
                });
            });
            pool.on('error', function (err, client) {  
                    console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack)
            })
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js 6 and anonymous objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997665/node-js-6-and-anonymous-objects)

Comment: `I was unable to get the data from anonymous block` - that's a bit of a nonsense. When an object is instantiated anonymously, it doesn't affect the object's functionality. If you were to show the code, the mistake would be easy to spot.